# How many different ways can the letters of the following word be arranged given the following conditions?

Tags: probability, statistics

The word is ***PAIRS***

The condition is

- The first letter cannot be a vowel

I thought that this was independent and tried to solve it the following ways

There are 5 letters so 5 different way to be arranged

I did 
$$3*5*5*5*5$$

As the first letter cannot be a vowel there is 3 chance that it is not a vowel, and i multiplied it by the chance that the other letter could be arranged. 
I did it but the answer was not correct, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: It must be 3*4*3*2*1

Comment: Why? why isn't it 3*5*4*3*2? could you explain

Comment: First letter must be a consonant and hence we have 3 choices. After filling the first place, we have 4 choices for the next letter, 3 for the third letter, and so on. I assume that the letters can not be reused.

Comment: I have another question if it is possible for you to answer, what if the letter r must be in the middle place, to solve this can i do this, 4*3*5*2*1? Or how do i solve this if my way wasn't correct

Comment: It will be 4*3*2*1. Since R is already placed, we have 4 letters and four places to fill. Hence 4! Ways. I assume the condition first letter should not be a vowel is not there. If it is there, then it is 2*3*2*1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44710/discussion-between-math-asker-and-muralidharan).